# get an element deep within a soap response

Tags: java, soa, saaj

Ok, so I am getting the following as the soap response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetCustomerDetailsByDeviceNumberResponse xmlns="http://services.domain.com/SelfCare">
            <GetCustomerDetailsByDeviceNumberResult xmlns:a="http://datacontracts.domain.com/SelfCare" 
              xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:AuditReferenceNumber i:nil="true"/>
                    <a:accounts>
                        <a:Account>
                            <a:lastInvoiceAmount>0</a:lastInvoiceAmount>
                        <a:lastInvoiceDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</a:lastInvoiceDate>
                    </a:Account>
                </a:accounts>
            </GetCustomerDetailsByDeviceNumberResult>
        </GetCustomerDetailsByDeviceNumberResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am trying to get the value of `<a:lastInvoiceDate></a:lastInvoiceDate>` with this piece of code:

```
SOAPBody sBody = response.getSOAPBody();
QName gcdbdbr = new QName("http://services.domain.com/SelfCare", "GetCustomerDetailsByDeviceNumberResponse");
java.util.Iterator iterator = sBody.getChildElements(gcdbdbr);
while(iterator.hasNext()){
      NodeList nodeList = sBody.getElementsByTagName("lastInvoiceDate");
      Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
      Node child = element.getFirstChild();
      String data = child.getTextContent();
      System.out.println(data);
}
```

but it's empty.

How do I get the value of `<a:lastInvoiceDate>`?

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems fine, but when you use `getElementsByTagName()` you also have to include the namespace in the string argument, like so:

```
...    
NodeList nodeList = sBody.getElementsByTagName("a:lastInvoiceDate");
...
```

If you want to omit the namespace in your lookup you can alternatively use the function `getElementsByTagNameNS()` with the wildcard `'*'` as the first argument and your nodename as the second one, like so:

```
NodeList nodeList = sBody.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "lastInvoiceDate");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo do not need to iterate

```
SOAPBody sBody = response.getSOAPBody();
NodeList nodeList = sBody.getElementsByTagName("lastInvoiceDate");
// Here you only need to loop nodeList if you have multiple elements with the same tag name
System.out.println(nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
```